# Flutter adding edit button left of container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm looking for a way around to achieve something like below attached image in flutter:

[image]

I will like the edit button to be like above image like a floatactionbutton.

I tried below code and wasn't able to achieve the above image:

```
Stack(

children[

Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
         image: AssetImage("assets/policyback.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
 ),

  Positioned(
      bottom: 1,
      right: 1,
  child: Container(
      child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.grey),
               ),
                                 
       )
     )

 ]
)
```

Comment: You can wrap your container and the button with a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) the button will be positioned bottom right, with some shadows.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: I just posted what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Edited working code and tested:

        Stack(
          children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-150,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/policyback.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70,right: 10),
              child: OverflowBox(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo, color: Colors.green,size: 70),
              ),
            ),
          ]
      )
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqZDW.jpg]

Comment: This didn't work. Thanks

Comment: OverflowBox with alignment and padding do the trick...have a good day!!! for edit button style use MaterialButton Widget... refer https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialButton-class.html

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work on mobile.

Comment: sorry for that i check it for web only, you can make it responsive to work this in mobile too

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, I have try using [**`Stack`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) Widget. also refer [**`Positioned`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

```
Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 320,
      width: 420,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              10,
            ),
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/27/11/23/cat-7094808__340.jpg',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 5,
      right: 40,
      child: Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Button Pressed');
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.edit,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 40,
      left: 50,
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          'User Name',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Result Screen->  [image]